# About Turing machine. what is Turing machine of $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$?

Tags: first-order-logic, turing-machines

[image]

Now I can not even start what to do..

Im wondering What is Turing machine of $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ = the greteat integer $\leq n/2.$

Comment: Can you please type out your question?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Imagine doing this function on a number in binary, what does the input and output look like and how do they compare to each other?

Comment: How are you representing numbers?

Comment: Maybe you could try writing $2n$ $1$'s. Return to start and move $n$ slots and write a $0$. Now count the number of pairs of $1$s before you hit $0$.